# How to manage if/else conditions in the execution chain of CUDA kernels to ensure uninterrupted execution on GPU?

Tags: cuda

I have number of image tiles as input to the series of CUDA kernels. In this execution chain, output of one step is used as input for the further steps, without copying back the intermediate output in the host memory.

```
cudaKernel1(inputImage, out1, stream);
cudaKernel2(out1, out2, stream);
cudaKernel3(out2, out3, stream);
....
cudaKernelN(..., ..., stream);
```

But for a certain scenario I have to include `if/else` condition in the execution chain, for which I have to copy back the result to the host memory.

```
cudaKernel1(inputImage, output1, stream);
cudaKernel2(out1, out2, stream);
cudaKernel3(out2, out3, stream);
....
cudaKernel11(out10, out11,stream);

copyDtoHAsync(temp,out11, stream);

cuStreamSynchronize(stream);

if(SOME_CONDITION_ON_temp)
{ 
    cudaKernel12(out11, out12, stream);
    cudaKernel13(out12, out13, stream);
    cudaKernel14(out13, out14, stream);
    .........
}
```

In the above scenario the `copyDtoHAsync`, `cuStreamSynchronize` and `if` calls are the stream blocking calls.

Suppose I have 100 input tiles given as input and getting executed on multiple GPU streams simultaneously. for 40 tiles if condition is true, for remaining 60 it is false. What is the BEST way to manage such intermediate blocking calls? How can I ensure uninterrupted execution of those 40 tiles on GPU without getting blocked because of those blocking calls?

Any post, similar problem, relevant examples will be appreciated.

Comment: Move the if portion of the algorithm to the GPU.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Yes, but then the result of 'if', lets say a flag saying true or false need to be sent to all the further kernels within the 'if' code block. And moreover with this design I have to send all 100 tiles in the if block kernels also, which I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [openMP](http://openmp.org/wp/). Something like

```
cudaStream_t streams[num_tiles];
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<num_tiles; i++)
{
    cudaStreamCreate( &streams[i]);

    cudaKernel1(inputImage, output1, stream[i]);
    cudaKernel2(out1, out2, stream[i]);
    cudaKernel3(out2, out3, stream[i]);
    ...
    cudaKernel11(out10, out11,stream[i]);

    copyDtoHAsync(temp,out11, stream[i]);

    cuStreamSynchronize(stream[i]);

    if(SOME_CONDITION_ON_temp)
    { 
        cudaKernel12(out11, out12, stream[i]);
        cudaKernel13(out12, out13, stream[i]);
        cudaKernel14(out13, out14, stream[i]);
        .........
    }

    cudaStreamDestroy(stream[i]);
}
```